# What monsters do I kill for hides?

Tags: the-witcher-3

What monsters do I kill to get a monster hide? I've been trying to get one for ages but I still can't find any.

Comment: Killed a chort, no hide killed a necrophage, no hide. There is no guarantee that you'll get a hide even if you kill the correct monster unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

Larger monsters can drop "x Hide". You can dismantle this, at a crafter, to get generic Monster Hide.

Example, Necrophage Hide becomes Monster hide and Monster blood:

[image: Dismantle Screen]

You can convert these items into monster hide:

- Necrophage Hide
- Troll Hide
- Werewolf Hide
- Ekimmara Hide
- Beserker Hide
- Chort Hide

Comment: Where do I find this monster called Necrophage?

Comment: @Rhcfref Necrophage is a type of monster, usually a carrion feeding undead, such as a Drowner or Ghoul

Comment: The point is that it doesn't matter what type of monster you go after, as you can convert any non-animal hide into Monster hide (seemingly). You might also have some luck looting monster nests.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing though... I've been killing monsters for 2 hours nearly and haven't got 1 hide or anything that can be dismantled into one

Comment: @Rhcfref Please see my updated answer. Hope that helps (carapace too).

Comment: @Rhcfref: In addition, I most recently found Necrophage Hide from a Devourer (basically a higher level Rotfiend).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for monsters to get monster carapace and monster hide needed for upgrades of Witcher Gear. Unfortunately I had already slain all big monsters, done all quests, destroyed all monster nests, etc (OCD anyone?).

But I found this cave I visited before with a bunch of respawned Devourers close to the entrance, a Harpy or 4 furthermore down the cave and 3 Erynia flying monsters at the bottom. On my first visit to this cave I had looted and killed everything, so imagine my joy that all these monsters respawned in between visits.

And - JAY! – I got me 3 Necrophage hides amongst others. And those can be dismantled into monster hides and/or monster carapace. You can find the cave next to the fast travel point of Clan fordarroch Forge – Skellige (south-west of Kaer Trolde).