# Where do I find monster carapace?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've been looking everywhere for monster carapace but I cannot find it. Any idea where it's found? I need to to craft mastercraft armour. If you know where it's for me then what monster do I kill for it?

Comment: Always check through your items at a Blacksmith or Armourer in the Dismantle tab to ensure it's not an item which can be got from dismantling another item.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Similar to my answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221112/what-monsters-do-i-kill-for-hides/221114#221114), talking about Monster Hide, you can dismantle materials such as Wyvern Hide into Monster Carapace.

[image: Wyvern Hide Dismantle]

According to other sources, you can also purchase it at high level armorsmiths, though I have not seen that.

You can convert these items into monster carapace:

- Basilisk Hide
- Forktail Hide
- Wyvern Hide

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for monsters to get monster carapace and monster hide needed for upgrades of Witcher Gear. Unfortunately I had already slain all big monsters, done all quests, destroyed all monster nests, etc (OCD anyone?).

But I found this cave I visited before with a bunch of respawned Devourers close to the entrance, a Harpy or 4 furthermore down the cave and 3 Erynia flying monsters at the bottom. On my first visit to this cave I had looted and killed everything, so imagine my joy that all these monsters respawned in between visits.

And - JAY! – I got me 3 Necrophage hides amongst others. You can find the cave next to the fast travel point of Clan fordarroch Forge – Skellige (south-west of Kaer Trolde).

Comment: Would you mind adding the exact location of this cave, possibly with a screenshot? I think I know the one you mean, but I can't be certain.